# Regular expression to accept a phone number with or without a leading "+"

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to query and get records from my database in my controller using:

```
FeedBack.where(:phone => @customer.phone)
```

But I will have `@customer.phone` optionally starting with `+`.

```
+919123455667
911234567890
```

I need to skip the `+` symbol at the beginning and get records for both scenarios.

How do I do this?

Comment: By making regex `lazy` using `?`.

Comment: @noob:- I am very weak at regular expression. So can you paste how the complete query looks like

Comment: Are you trying to match an **`Indian`** mobile phone number ? @Gavriel has already posted an answer. But I will also post my answer soon.

Comment: @noob. Yes. I am trying to match Indian mobile number. I tried like below FeedBack.where(:phone => @customer.phone(/^\+?/) ).. But returned some syntax error

Comment: rubyist: I have posted my answer keeping in mind the **Indian** phone numbers.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421, along with "[ask]" and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1):

Start your regex like this:

```
/^\+?/
```

so it matches strings that optionally start with a "+". For example:

```
/^\+?[0-9]+/
```

Or do you mean to remove the leading plus?

```
FeedBack.where(:phone => @customer.phone.gsub(/^\+?/, ''))
```

Or:

```
clearedPhone = @customer.phone.gsub(/^\+?/, '')
FeedBack.where(["phone='?' or phone='+?'", clearedPhone, clearedPhone])
```

Or:

```
FeedBack.where(:phone =>[clearedPhone, "+#{clearedPhone}"])
```

Comment: I tried like below FeedBack.where(:phone => @customer.phone(/^\+?/) ).. But returned some syntax error

Comment: - I dont need  to remove the leading plus.. My purpose it to retrieve records when an input of phone number is give with both + and without +

Comment: In my table in db, there are records which has phone numbers which has starting with + and without + symbol

Comment: FeedBack.where(:phone => @customer.phone.gsub(/^\+?/, ''))

Comment: your question wasn't tagged by SQL, do you want an SQL solution with `... AND phone LIKE "%123456"` or `... AND (phone="123456" OR phone="+123456")` ?

Comment: @rubyist, not the call, we know that, the function body

Comment: def index @feedbacks = FeedBack.where(:phone => @customer.phone.gsub(/^\+?/, ''))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102253/discussion-between-rubyist-and-gavriel).

Answer (score 1):

I guess from prefix `+91` that you are trying to match an **Indian** mobile phone number. Following is my regex.

**RegEx**: `/\+?(?:91)[789][0-9]{9}/`

**Explanation**:

1) `\+?` makes `+` optional.

2) `(?:91)` matches `91` as prefix.

3) `[789]` as mobile numbers in **India** start with `7 8 or 9` this matches either of those as first digit of number.

4) `[0-9]{9}` matches rest of the `9` digits of number.

<kbd>[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rL3jQ1/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with phone numbers, you'll also have to deal with spaces like `+45 34 45 65 26` or `+61 2 9222 1234`.  If the phone numbers in the database are all with/without the `+` try:

```
def scrub_the_phone_number(number)
  number.gsub(/[^\d]/, '')
end

FeedBack.where(phone: scrub_the_phone_number(@customer.phone))
```

This is substituting all non-digit characters with an empty string and returning the result.

If however, your database contains phone records of various formats, you will need clean that data or query for each format like:

```
FeedBack.where("phone LIKE %?", scrub_the_phone_number(@customer.phone))
```

This will match anything ending in a pure number.